# Grouping in MySQL with a Not condition

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table browsers_list that has the following data.

```
name
--------------
Internet Explorer 8.0
Internet Explorer 9.0
Internet Explorer 10.0
Internet Explorer 11.0
Firefox 9.0.1
Firefox 6.0.2
Firefox 3.6.27
Safari 533.1
Safari 534.48.3
Safari 534.54.16
Opera 9.80
Chrome x.x.x
Chrome x.x.x
Chrome x.x.x
```

I require to group this list so that I get the following output.

```
name
--------------
Internet Explorer 8.0
Internet Explorer 9.0
Internet Explorer 10.0
Internet Explorer 11.0
Firefox
Safari
Opera
Chrome
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like, though this is in a different order:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
      WHEN Name LIKE 'Internet Explorer%' THEN Name
      ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 1)
    END AS NewName
FROM TableA
GROUP BY NewName
```

Comment: I was just putting in something similar.  Here is a reference to the case statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html